# Perform a Vlook Up or Find Per column

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me,

Take for example i have a this kind of data set

In Sheet1

```
Column A
614545
546425
456426
```

In Sheet 4, I have a named table like this:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C

614545      AAA         1111
564645      AXS         1254
123545      XSF         4524
(And so forth...)
```

Now what i need is a code that would search For the corresponding Value of Sheet 1 Column A to the table in sheet 4. As for example, the code would give this result

Sheet1

```
Column A    Col B   Col C
614545      AAA     CCC
```

(And so forth...)

I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks now. But I just couldnt fix it. I am onl able to perform a find function at one cell at a time. I need a code that would traverse to the whole column A (Sheet1) and would return the corresponding values on the table in sheet(4).

Please help me.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your example, where does `CCC` come from? I can see how `614545` in Sheet 1 maps to `614545 / AAA / 1111` but I cannot see where `CCC` come from?

Comment: That's my bad. It should be 1111 instead of ccc. Sorry about that.

Comment: you may consider editing your post to reflect that `1111` is required so that potential helpers have a clear understanding of problem and desired solution...

Comment: Show us what you've "been trying for weeks", so we can help. Else search this site; this question has been been answered a hundred times over.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - you'll need to update the data ranges as per your requirements

```
Sub LookUpValues()
    Dim sourceRng As Range, dataTable As Range, cl As Range

    Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10") 
    Set dataTable = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:C100") 

    For Each cl In sourceRng
        cl.Offset(0, 1) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, dataTable, 2, False)
        cl.Offset(0, 2) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, dataTable, 3, False)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Well the thing is i need it on a vba code. Actually i have developed a code already. But it is not that really effective. The code goes like this `Dim rngFindRange As Range
Dim i As Integer


Set rngFindRange = Workbooks("latesttest").Sheets("RC").Range("rctable").Find(Range("C3"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not rngFindRange Is Nothing Then

Range("D3") = rngFindRange.Offset(0, 1)
Range("E3") = rngFindRange.Offset(0, 2)
Range("F3") = rngFindRange.Offset(0, 3)`  But as you can see the code is only made for a single range. Im a beginner here in vba. So pardon the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add 'VLookup' is perfectly fine in most cases but if your Excel data starts to become large then 'VLookup' is notoriously slow. The .Find method is much quicker.

This example UDF function - use formula in Excel `=AltLookup(cell,column)` Eg `=AltLookup(A1,3)` will lookup the text in cell A1 on Sheet1 in column A:A of Sheet4 and return column 3 or column C

```
Function AltLookup(ByVal strToFind As String, ByVal column As Long)
Dim rngFind As Range

With Sheet4 'change sheet to lookup on

    With .Columns("A:A") 'assuming lookup on column A

    Set rngFind = .Find(What:=strToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        AltLookup = .Cells(rngFind.Row, column).Value
    Else
        'do nothing or.. AltLookup = vbnullstring
    End If

    End With
End With
End Function
```